# Why Could glGetString(GL_VERSION) Be Causing a Seg Fault?

Tags: c, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL on Fedora 13 and noticed that a call to glGetString is causing a seg fault.  I've scraped Google, but come up with no solutions.

The code is simple:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>

int main() {
    glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile Command:

```
g++ -lGL main.cpp -o test.bin
```

Run result:

```
$ ./test.bin 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

OpenGL Info:

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) IGDNG_M GEM 20100328 2010Q1 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.8.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
```

Any ideas or references are greatly appreciated.

**Solution:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow("test");
    glutFullScreen();
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I doubt you can call even something as simple as glGetString without [an OpenGL context](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context).

Comment: I think you're right.  The docs of glGetString say it returns information about the "current GL connection" but I don't think the original poster has initialized this connection.  http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetString.xml

Comment: Direct hit!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: wow... been racking my head for half an hour wondering if I had forgotten everything about pointers turns out I was calling it at the wrong time lol! Thanks, as simple as this answer is it is very insightful